# Adding multiple project inside the existing firebase project

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

Is there any way to add another new project inside the existing firebase project?

I've been trying to figure it out but could not find any, Would really appreciate if someone can help me out on this matter, would really appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your project in firebase and go to the setting and scroll down to "Your apps"
Here you can add project by clicking on "Add App" button on the right side.[image]

Comment: But I would like it to use the same database

Comment: You can use same database as the project is same

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you please make as accepted.